# Selenium web scraping under dropdown list

Tags: list, selenium, web, dropdown, screen-scraping

Selenium web scraping :

1. Dropdown list change
2. tried to changed results scraping
3. failed

Code:

```
'''
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
import time

driver=webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\Program Files\Python39\chromedriver.exe')
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("https://www.gastite.com/locator/?cats=109")

for i in range(1,3,1):
    state=driver.find_element(By.NAME, 'state')
    stateDD=Select(state)
    stateDD.select_by_index(i)
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="content"]/div[3]/form/input[2]')
    time.sleep(2)
    lists=driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("div.repcontent > a")
    #print(lists)
    for list in lists:
        company=list.find_element_by_class_name('namelink company_title').text
        address=list.find_element_by_class_name('address').text
        address1=list.find_element_by_class_name('address2').text
        tel=list.find_element_by_tag_name('span').text
        fax=list.find_element_by_tag_name('span').text
        web=list.get_attribute('href')
        print(company, address, address1, tel, fax, web)
    
'''
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I select one state from the dropdownlist for an example and rest of the your attempt.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))

url ='https://www.gastite.com/locator/?cats=109' 
driver.maximize_window()

Select(WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//select[@name='state']")))).select_by_value("AL")

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source,'lxml')
data=[]
for card in soup.select('#resultscontainer > ul > li > div.repcontent'):
    company = card.select_one('h3.company_title').text
    print(company)
    address = card.select_one('div.address').text
    address2 = card.select_one('div.address2').text
    phone = card.select('span').contents[0]
    fax = card.select('span').contents[1]

    data.append({
        'company':company,
        'address':address,
        'address2':address2,
        'phone':phone,
        'fax':fax
        })
        
print(data)
```

Comment: I have error still even your code. I updated chromedriver as 100.0.4896 version.
--------------
====== WebDriver manager ======
Current google-chrome version is 100.0.4896
Get LATEST chromedriver version for 100.0.4896 google-chrome
Driver [C:\Users\brian\.wdm\drivers\chromedriver\win32\100.0.4896.60\chromedriver.exe] found in cache
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\92Python\50dropone.py", line 11, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'service'

Comment: @Brian chromedriverManager:https://pypi.org/project/webdriver-manager/